# Click on a button in IE page from VBA code

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to click on the addacquisitionButton but I am not able to do. 
I tried this code

```
Set div = ie.document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
Set div = ie.document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")(1) 
Set Button = div.getElementsByTagName("button")(2)  '
Button = IEDoc.getElemntsById("addAcquisitionButton")
Button.Click
```

but It doesn t work

This is the source code from my Html page

```
enter code here
<div class="common-box blue-box" id="actionsPanel" style="z-index: 100;">
    <div id="actionContainer" class="button-container">
        <button class="button buttonAction" id="dashboardButton">
            Retour à l'aperçu des demandes
        </button>

              <button class="button buttonAction" id="addAcquisitionButton"> 
                 Ajouter acquisition/importation
              </button>


            <button class="button buttonAction" id="attachButton">
                Attacher documents
            </button>


    </div>
```

Where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to search for elements by id. Try setting the div this way.

```
Set div = ie.document.body.getElementsById("actionContainer")
```

And retrieve the button the same way

```
Set Button = div.getElementsById("addAcquisitionButton")
```

Answer (score 0):

I goterror 438,
Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method